# How to calculate exact months between two dates

Tags: php, date

Consider there are 44 days between two dates.The result what I want is 2 months and not 1 month or 1 month 14 days.I have tried several date functions in both php and mysql,but failed in obtaining the exact result. I've also tried my own(below)code.

```
 $dt1 = some date
        $dt2 = some date

    $date1 = date_create("".$dtl."");

    $date2 = date_create("".$dt2."");

    $dateDiff = date_diff($date2, $date1);

    $probDays = $dateDiff->days;
    $probMon =  $dateDiff->m;
    $probYear = $dateDiff->y;

    $month = $probDays / 30;
    $totLeave = $month * 1;

   if($month > $probmon)
   { 
    $totLeave = $totLeave + 1;
   }
```

But I failed.The code is about adding vacation days to the client.Any solution in php or mysql would be grateful.Thanks in advance for all the volunteers.

Comment: is there a halfway mark like under 10 days dont count the month or the oposite, even if its a minute in the new month count the entire month?

Comment: also you wrote $dtl instead of $dt1 here. but I guess thats a typo

Comment: no halfway marks.30+1 days must give 2 months(pls keep in mind about february month).Dont consider minutes or even hours.Also $dtl is not an issue,actually it is $dt1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using PHP 5.3, maybe you could try the following:

```
<?php
$dt1 = "2014-05-12";
$dt2 = "2014-06-15";
$date1 = new DateTime($dt1);
$date2 = new DateTime($dt2);
$months = $date1->diff($date2)->m;
$days = $date1->diff($date2)->d;
if ($days >= 1) $months++;
echo $months." months!";
?>
```

Comment: Also add `12 * $date1->diff($date2)->y` to account for dates that are more than a year apart.

Comment: The above code worked and I am getting the exact result what I expected.Once again thank you for all.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check number of days, if not equal to zero, then add 1 to months count and return that value of months.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$dt_dif= $dt2 - $dt1 ;

$y = $tot_exp / 365;
$d = $tot_exp % 365;
$m = $d / 30;

$year = (int)$y;
$month = (int)$m;
$day= (int)$d;

$total="".$month."month(s) ".$day."day(s)";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

John Riedel answer is the correct one!

You need to use $start_date->diff($end_date)->m & $start_date->diff($end_date)->d to find out the month & date differences.. and if the days count is more than 0, then you need to increase the months count as stated here...

http://www.phpguy.in/finding-difference-between-2-dates-in-php/

Answer (score 0):

```
    $date_from = "2011-01-22";
    $date_to = "2011-03-23";
    $date_from = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date_from));
    $date_to = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date_to));
    $y1 = date('Y', strtotime($date_from));
    $y2 = date('Y', strtotime($date_to));
    $m1 = date('m', strtotime($date_from));
    $m2 = date('m', strtotime($date_to));
    $day1 = date('d', strtotime($date_from));
    $day2 = date('d', strtotime($date_to));
    $yearDiff = $y2 - $y1;
    if ($m2 > $m1) {
        $month = $m2 - $m1;
    } else {
        $month = 0;
    }

    if ($yearDiff > 0 && $m1 > $m2) {
        $yearMonth = (($yearDiff * 12) - ($m1 - $m2));
    } else {
        $yearMonth = $yearDiff * 12;
    }

    if ($day1 > $day2) {
        $month = ($month - 1);
    }
    $total_month = $yearMonth + $month;
    $total_month = ($total_month > 1) ? $total_month . " months" : $total_month . " month";
    echo "Total " . $total_month;
```